# Updated Stanford dependencies manual

Tags: stanford-nlp

Does anyone know where to find an updated version of the Stanford typed dependencies manual, or something similar?  [This](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf) is available on the web, but it's from 2008 and it seems they have changed the labeling conventions somewhat. I am looking for detailed definitions of the dependency labels, hopefully with examples like those in the linked document.